# Fazer com que as colunas do Bootstrap preencham 100% a largura da row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Creio que seja algo simples, mas como sou iniciante no Bootstrap ainda não descobri como fazer.

O que eu quero é que as colunas preencham a largura total da row, coloquei uma borda vermelha nos lados dela para facilitar o entendimento.

Sei que é o padding das colunas que da esse espaçamento, mas eu quero preencher a row sem remover o espaço entre as colunas.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h2sj2nbL/1/)

```css
.box {
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" style="margin-top:40px;margin-bottom:40px;border-right: 1px solid red;border-left: 1px solid red;">
    <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
      <div class="box"></div>
     </div>
    <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Gabriel qual é a necessidade dessa ocupação 100%? Se você tirar as bordas não da pra perceber se a col está ocupando 100% ou 90%.. não faz diferença. Se fizermos a coluna 'grudar' na row, toda vez que a quebra de media acontecer ela ficará estranha e desalinhada.

Comment: Gabriel, um feedback seria interessante!

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que não exista necessidade de fazer a coluna preencher a row 100%, mas como eu já comentei isso na pergunta, vamos seguir em frente.

**O que foi feito:**

- **HTML**

Adicionei `id` para cada `div` de `class='box'` (A,B,C,D), para que possam sofrer de forma independente a manipulação do javascript.

- **CSS**

Adicionada a classe `first` que reduz o `margin-left` do elemento em -15px.

Adicionada a classe `last` que reduz o `margin-right` do elemento em -15px.

**Lógica por trás das classes `first` e `last`:**

Quando o elemento é o **primeiro** de sua "linha" ele deve ficar encostado na borda esquerda de seu elemento pai (no caso a coluna).

Quando o elemento é o **último** de sua "linha" ele deve ficar encostado na borda direita de seu elemento pai (no caso a coluna).

**Mas porque -15px? :** `15px` é o `padding` padrão da coluna definido pelo bootstrap. Então definimos que o elemento filho irá ter `-15px` de `margin` para cancelar a ação do `padding`.

- **JQuery**

Utilizando o Jquery, criei a função **encostar**, que nada mais é do que a responsável por fazer as trocas de classes definidas anteriormente no **CSS**. (encostando o elemento na borda mais próxima).

Quando houver uma quebra de linha ou uma mudança de [media](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/overview/), a função deve detectar e realocar as div's de forma correta.

**Lógica por trás da realocação:** Utilizando o [offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) do jquery, é possível pegar a posição exata em que o elemento se encontra na página, dessa forma podemos pegar a posição do último elemento `id='D'` e subtrair pela posição do primeiro elemento `id='A'`. Enquanto eles estiverem na mesma linha, a distância entre eles será de `853.5px`. Dessa forma eu consigo detectar a hora exata em que ocorre a quebra de linha.

Quando ocorre a quebra de linha, o último elemento perde a classe `last` e recebe a classe `first`, porquê agora ele é o primeiro da linha de baixo.

E é claro que sobrou um elemento na linha de cima, e agora ele precisa receber a classe `last`.

Para que a realocação das div's funcione, estou usando os eventos [.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) e [.resize()](http://api.jquery.com/resize/), que juntos são capazes de detectar quando a página foi totalmente carregada e toda vez que ela estiver sendo redimensionada.

- **Minha sinceridade**

Não acredito que este código esteja da melhor forma possível, mas cumpre seu papel em relação a pergunta feita.

Infelizmente esse código funciona apenas quando estamos falando das 4 div's criadas (A,B,C,D).

**Existe uma forma de fazer a realocação para um número indeterminado de divs?:** Acredito que sim, mas não fui capaz de pensar dessa forma (talvez um pouco mais de persistência e eu chego la!).

A visualização deste código também está disponível [aqui](https://codepen.io/BrunoCastro/pen/MozNmP).

```js
$(document).ready(encostar);
$(window).on('resize',encostar);

function encostar(){
 
  var vet = [];
  
  $('.box').each(function(){
    
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    
   // $(this).text(offset.left+'px');
    
    vet[$(this).attr('id')] = offset.left;
    
    var out = '';
    for (var i in vet) {
        out += i + ": " + vet[i] + "\n";
    }
        
    if(vet['D'] - vet['A'] < 853.5)
      {       

        $('#D').addClass('first');
        $('#D').removeClass('last');
        
        if($('#C').hasClass('first'))
          {
            
          }
        else
          {
            $('#C').addClass('last');
          }    
        
        if(vet['B'] === vet['D'])
          {
              $('#D').removeClass('first');
              $('#D').addClass('last');
              $('#B').removeClass('first');
              $('#B').addClass('last');
          }
        
        if(vet['A'] === vet['C']-15)
          {
            $('#C').addClass('first');
            $('#C').removeClass('last');
            
            if($(window).width() < 575)
            {
               $('#A').addClass('last');
               $('#C').addClass('last');
               $('#B').addClass('first');
               $('#B').addClass('last');
               $('#D').addClass('first');
               $('#D').addClass('last');
            }
            else
              {
               $('#A').removeClass('last');
               $('#C').removeClass('last');
               $('#B').removeClass('first');
               $('#D').removeClass('first');
              }
            
          }
        
      }
    else
      {   
   
        $('#D').removeClass('first');
        $('#D').addClass('last');
        $('#C').removeClass('last'); 
        $('#C').removeClass('first');  
        $('#B').removeClass('last'); 
      }
    
 
    
  });
 
}
```

```css
.box {
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  text-align: center;
}


.first{
  
    margin-left: -15px !important;
  
}


.last{
  
    margin-right: -15px !important;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" style="margin-top:40px;margin-bottom:40px;border-right: 1px solid red;border-left: 1px solid red;">
    <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
      <div class="box first" id='A'></div>
     </div>
    <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
      <div class="box" id='B'></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
      <div class="box" id='C'></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
      <div class="box last" id='D'></div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

*Não esqueça de redimensionar o navegador!*

Comment: Desculpa a demora para dar um feedback. Obrigado pelo código, mas teria que ser uma solução dinâmica, sem limite de colunas.

Comment: Ok, é sempre bom esclarecer na pergunta também!

Answer (score 0):

O que veio à minha cabeça no momento é criar duas classes para suas colunas. Uma que ficará do lado esquerdo, com padding apenas na direita. E outra que ficará sempre na direita, com padding somente na esquerda. Com isso, elas ocupariam 100% do frame e continuariam separadas.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row" style="margin-top:40px;margin-bottom:40px;border-right: 1px solid red;border-left: 1px solid red;">
  <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-left">
    <div class="box"></div>
 </div>
<div class="col-xl-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-right">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-xl-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-left">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-xl-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-right">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

```
    .box {
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  padding: (0,0,0,0)
}

.col-left {
  padding-left: 0px;
 }

 .col-right {
  padding-right: 0px;
 }
```

Segue o JS Fiddle abaixo, em que fiz minhas edições:
[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h2sj2nbL/2/)

Comment: Pedro, isso não resolve o problema, as colunas do meio não possuem mais espaço entre elas.

Comment: Sim, não resolve. Eu tinha entendido errado a pergunta!

Answer (score 0):

As linhas vermelhas do seu snippet devem estar encostadas nas laterais? De acordo com a [documentação de containers](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container) você pode trocar a classe `container` por `container-fluid`:

```css
.box {
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row" style="margin-top:40px;margin-bottom:40px;border-right: 1px solid red;border-left: 1px solid red;">
    <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Renan não são as linhas vermelhas que devem encostar, são as div's box, que devem encostar na linha vermelha.